# Hidden text in application menu

Tags: menu

I'm sure I'm not the first to ask this, but I searched and found no answer.

When I search in the application menu for example "python" I have version 2.7 and version 3.8, and the rest of the line is not displayed on the screen, so it is impossible to know which icon belongs to version 2.7 and which to 3.8.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

[image: menu]

Comment: Install alacarte. You can change the name of Idle accordingly, eg. Idle-2.7 and Idle-3.8

Comment: Yes, but displaying the text of the icon is something very basic, I do not believe that the developers of Ubuntu did not think of a solution. Even when I stand with the mouse on the icon or right-click on it, the full text is not displayed.